# Point safe-config-service to hosted instance of safe-transaction-service

Tags: gnosis-safe

I was not able to find a way to add my hosted instance of safe-transaction-service to safe-config-service. How can do it?

---

I am switching to using [safe-infrastructure](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure).

However when running Step 3 (Add your chain info), my console throws the following error -

```
2022-02-01 11:40:24,177 [DEBUG] [MainProcess] Starting new HTTP connection (1): nginx:8000
2022-02-01 11:40:24,179 [DEBUG] [MainProcess] http://nginx:8000 "POST /v1/flush/some_random_token HTTP/1.1" 404 153
2022-02-01 11:40:24,179 [ERROR] [MainProcess] 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://nginx:8000/v1/flush/some_random_token
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

Note - I am inside the interactive console.

my **config.json** file

```
[
    {
        "model": "chains.chain",
        "pk": 421611,
        "fields": {
            "relevance": 100,
            "name": "Arbitrum Testnet",
            "short_name": "arb-rin",
            "description": "",
            "l2": true,
            "rpc_authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
            "rpc_uri": "https://rinkeby.arbitrum.io/rpc",
            "safe_apps_rpc_authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
            "safe_apps_rpc_uri": "https://rinkeby.arbitrum.io/rpc",
            "block_explorer_uri_address_template": "https://testnet.arbiscan.io/address/{{address}}",
            "block_explorer_uri_tx_hash_template": "https://testnet.arbiscan.io/tx/{{txHash}}",
            "currency_name": "Ether",
            "currency_symbol": "ETH",
            "currency_decimals": 18,
            "currency_logo_uri": "chains/4/currency_logo.jpg",
            "transaction_service_uri": "http://localhost:8000/txs",
            "vpc_transaction_service_uri": "http://localhost:8000/txs",
            "theme_text_color": "#ffffff",
            "theme_background_color": "#000000",
            "ens_registry_address": null,
            "recommended_master_copy_version": "1.3.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Safe team currently only adds instances of the Safe transaction service that is hosted by them. You would have to host your own instance of the config service and the interface.

Comment: Okay got it!

I am unable to find where to put url of safe-transition-service in safe-config-service.  Can you please point it out?

Comment: You can take a look on our infrastructure repo https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure